# How to use css to change <pre> font size

Tags: html, css, font-size, pre

```
pre{font-family:cursive;font-style:italic;font-size:xxx-small}
```

How to change `pre` font size?

Answer (score 46):

While the font-size cannot be changed for text directly inside pre tags, you can always wrap that text in another element (a span, for example) and change the font size of that element.

For example (this is inline-styles, but could be put in CSS if you wanted):

```
<pre><span class="inner-pre" style="font-size: 11px">
Blah blah
Multiple lines and no br's!
Oh yeah!
</span></pre>
```

Comment: I almost didn't try this because I didn't think it could possibly work since the tag is inside the pre tag...but it does work (at least with the outlook html interpreter).  Thanks!

Comment: If you are using `<pre><code></code></pre>`, remember to set `pre code { white-space: pre; }` to preserve line breaks.

Comment: I've found this incredibly helpful when emailing powershell text output to a teams channel (need the preformatted so you don't lose column spacing + need a smaller font) +1

Answer (score 13):

Your issue is probably due to Courer being used as the default font, if you set Courier New as the preferred font it should be fine.

The following works fine in both Firefox & IE

```
pre {
   font-family: "courier new", courier, monospace;
   font-size: 11px;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

If you only need to change the font size once, you can write

```
<pre style="font-size: 10px">
    ...
</pre>
```

Comment: In Chrome it did change the font size, but "added" (?) significant spacing in between the lines, more or less nullifying the effect.

Answer (score 9):

Take a look here:

[PRE - preformatted text](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/HTML3.2/5.44.html)

[HTML  tag](http://www.codetoad.com/html/text/pre_tag.html)

> You cannot change font size within a
>   PRE element (and you cannot put a PRE
>   element inside a FONT  element, for
>   example), but the BASEFONT element
>   affects preformatted text, too.

Comment: Second link is dead :(

Comment: @Jankapunkt the page changed extension from .asp to .html. :) Thanks for the hint.

Comment: it's always best to post an actual response (even copy/paste) instead of just the link to external resources, because websites and blogs may have a shorter life than stackoverflow

Answer (score 6):

One solution to fixing font size on `pre` tags is to use:

```
pre
{
    white-space: pre-wrap !important;
}
```

This fixes font sizes on mobile browsers, which cannot accurately determine the width of a `pre` element.

Source: [Font size of pre tag on mobile devices gets too big – a fix](https://logincorrect.wordpress.com/2014/03/15/controlling-size-pre-tag-mobile-devices/)

Answer (score 4):

Here is the  <kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/2VdBF/2/)**</kbd>

I am not quite sure why my browsers (chrome, FF, IE) doesn't agree!

Please let me know if I am missing something.

HTML

```
<pre>
Test
</pre>
```

css

```
pre {
    font-size: 100px;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

Chrome

[image]

Firefox

[image]

IE

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Sorry for digging up an old issue. After searching high and low for "why browsers (specially mobile browsers) renders `<pre>` tags text too small and unreadable", I found as suggested here, changing css `font-size:` to `em` helps. But the gotcha is `em` for `<pre>` effects size differently on desktop browser then on mobile brower. A clear discrepancy noticeable on android Samsung/Mozilla/Chrome increase in font-size less for the same value of `em` then desktop browsers. The solution to this dilemma is to use `%` instead of `em`.

The css rule `pre{font-size:200%;}` seems to enlarge `<pre>` text more consistently (compare to other texts) on mobile browser as it does on desktop browser.

Answer (score 2):

I think it can have something to do with the standard fonts supported by different browsers. Try your code in different browsers but remember IE is not W3 compatible.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's the right way to do it, but this worked for me in Firefox:

```
font: normal 11px Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
```