# <pre> tag markup

Tags: html, css, fonts, pre

Is it possible to change the font from the `<pre>` tag? For example, I don't like the courier font, but I do like the consolas font. Hod od I change this in css?

I tried the following:

```
pre {
    color: white;
    font: "Consolas";
}
```

but that didn't work in Firefox/IE...

Thank you!

Yvan

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995022/pre-tag-and-css-font-family

Comment: You should consider listing more fonts, for example this is what Stack Overflow uses: `font-family: Consolas, Menlo, Monaco, Lucida Console, Liberation Mono, DejaVu Sans Mono, Bitstream Vera Sans Mono, Courier New, monospace, serif`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `font` shorthand property requires that you specify the font size.

Use the `font-family` property instead.

Answer (score 0):

font-family should work. try

```
.pre {
    color: #fff;
    font-family:Consolas;
}
```